# ¿SE PUEDE CAMBIAR EL ICONO DE SHOWINFO DEL MODULO MESSAGEBOX?

Tags: python, tkinter

[image]

Quiero cambiar el icono señalado por otro

Alguna idea?

Comment: claro que sí, ha varias formas, revisa esto: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560493/messagebox-show-custom-icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560493/messagebox-show-custom-icon)

Comment: ¿Framework gráfico? ¿tkinter quizás? ¿Con "icono" te refieres al de la barra de de título de la ventana o al que aparece al lado del mensaje dentro del diálogo?

Comment: mira esta respuesta: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815007/change-icon-for-tkinter-messagebox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815007/change-icon-for-tkinter-messagebox), es para personalizar el ícono de los messagebox de Tkinter.

Comment: NEOhitokiri ese es de C#, yo busco para el modulo de PYTHON                              FJSevilla me refiero al de dentro de la ventana

Comment: NEOhitokiri ese ya lo vi pero el que quiero cambiar es el de dentro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Se puede cambiar el icono interno que se muestra en un `MessageBox`?

Si y no.

Me explico, el constructor de `MessageBox` tiene un argumento llamado `icon` que permite cambiar dicho icono. Dicho argumento acepta las siguientes constantes:

- `"info"`
- `"warning"`
- `"error"`
- `"question"`

Son los iconos por defecto de `showinfo`, `showwarning`, `showerror` y `askquestion/askokcancel/askyesno/askretrycancel respectivamente.

El problema es por tanto que podemos modificar el icono, pero solo para usar otro de los iconos por defecto de los otros tipos de `MessageBox`.

```
from tkinter import messagebox

messagebox.showinfo("Test", "a Tk MessageBox", icon="error")
```

Si quieres más flexibilidad, siempre puedes crear tu propia clase derivando de `TopLevel` y crear tu diálogo modal.

Por ejemplo:

```
import PIL
import tkinter as tk


class InfoMessageBox(tk.Toplevel):

    DEFAULT_ICON = b'R0lGODlhMgAyAOfkAAClxwGlxwKlxwOlxwSlxwWlxwalxwelxwilxgilxwmlxwqlxwulxw+kxQ2l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\n'

    def __init__(
            self, root, *args, btn_text="Ok",
            title="Info", msg="", icon=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(root, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title(title)

        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.msg = msg
        self.icon = icon
        self.btn_text = str(btn_text)


        # Main frame
        main_frm = tk.Frame(self)
        main_frm.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH, padx=(10, 10), pady=10)

        # Icon
        if self.icon is not None:
            if isinstance(self.icon, tk.PhotoImage):
                h, w = self.icon.height(), self.icon.width()
                scale_w = w // 50
                scale_h = h // 50
                self.icon = self.icon.subsample(scale_w, scale_h)

            elif isinstance(self.icon, PIL.ImageFile.ImageFile):
                im = self.icon.resize((50, 50), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
                self.icon = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

            else:
                raise ValueError(
                    f"can't use {self.icon} as icon: not a photo image"
                    )
        else:
            self.icon = tk.PhotoImage(data=self.DEFAULT_ICON)

        icon_label = tk.Label(main_frm, image=self.icon)
        icon_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NE)

        # Message label
        message = tk.Label(
            main_frm,
            text=self.msg,
            anchor=tk.W,
            justify=tk.LEFT,
            wraplength=350,
            font='Helvetica 10 bold')
        message.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NW)
        main_frm.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Button
        ok_btn = tk.Button(
            main_frm,
            width=8,
            text=self.btn_text,
            command=self.on_close
            )
        ok_btn.bind('<KeyPress-Return>', func=self.on_close)
        ok_btn.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

        # Modal dialog
        self.transient(master=root)
        self.grab_set()
        ok_btn.focus_set()
        self.deiconify()

        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_close)

    def on_close(self, *args):
        self.grab_release()
        self.destroy()
        return "ok"
```

`DEFAULT_ICON` es una imágen gif en base64 que se usa como imágen por defecto:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500+500+500")
tk.Button(
    root,
    text="Abrir diálogo",
    command=lambda: InfoMessageBox(
        root,
        title="El Zen de Python",
        btn_text="Aceptar",
        msg=("Bello es mejor que feo.\n"
             "Explícito es mejor que implícito.\n"
             "Simple es mejor que complejo.\n"
             "Complejo es mejor que complicado.\n"
             "Plano es mejor que anidado.\n"
             "Espaciado es mejor que denso.\n"
             "La legibilidad es importante.\n"
             ),
        )
).place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para asignar otra imagen como icono solo hay que hacer uso del argumento `icon` y pasar:

- **Instancia de `tkinter.PhotoImage`**

  ```
  import tkinter as tk

  root = tk.Tk()
  root.geometry("500x500+500+500")

  img = tk.PhotoImage(file="/ruta/icono.gif")
  tk.Button(
      root,
      text="Abrir diálogo",
      command=lambda: InfoMessageBox(
          root,
          title="El Zen de Python",
          btn_text="Aceptar",
          msg=("Explícito es mejor que implícito.\n",
          icon=img
          )
  ).place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)
  root.mainloop()
  ```
- **Imagen cargada con PIL (`PIL.Image()`)**:

  ```
  import tkinter as tk
  from PIL import Image

  root = tk.Tk()
  root.geometry("500x500+500+500")

  img = Image.open("/ruta/incono.gif")
  tk.Button(
      root,
      text="Abrir diálogo",
      command=lambda: InfoMessageBox(
          root,
          title="El Zen de Python",
          btn_text="Ok",
          msg="Explícito es mejor que implícito.\n",
      icon=img
      )
  ).place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)
  root.mainloop()
  ```